# correct query in PyTables

Tags: python, performance, pytables

I am using Python 2.7, and trying to perform a PyTables query:

```
#Here the condition
selectedIndex = [1,6,7,9]
condition = 'IndexColumn in selectedIndex'

#here the query
for x1 in tab.where(condition,selectedIndex):
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

And I am getting:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'VariableNode' is not iterable
```

From the documentation about pytables, I am trying to use this:

```
Table.where(condition, condvars=None, start=None, stop=None, step=None)
```

And that:

```
condition = 'col1 == "AAAA"'

for record in table.where(condition):  # TypeError in Python3
    #do something with "record"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the `DataFrame.query` method instead? I don't think `where` takes string arguments ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way to do the in-kernel query using a string argument in your case would be:

```
conditon="(IndexColumn==1)|(IndexColumn==6)|(IndexColumn==7)|(IndexColumn==9)"
```

and IndexColumn needs to be the actual name of the column as specfied in  your IsDescription class. I believe the python condition "a in b" is not valid for Pytablles queries

EDIT concerning your comment:

```
"".join(["(IndexColumn==%i)|"%j for j in selectedIndex])[:-1]
```

should give you the correct string for the query.

Comment: This is a problem then, because if I need to declare each condition, I cannot send the whole `selectedIndex` doing something like this `def processTable(selectedIndex)`, am I right?

Comment: no you can just concatenate the appropriate strings with something like this: ''.join(["(IndexColumn==%i)|"%j for j in selectedIndex])[:-1]